# Jquery preventDefault for the parent link only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input radios element as a children of a hyperlinks as the following:

```
<li ><a href="/ar/news/source/?source=2"><input type="radio" class="searchSrc" name="searchSrc" value="2"  style="display: inline" />&nbsp;الشروق</a></li>

<li ><a href="/ar/news/source/?source=3"><input type="radio" class="searchSrc" name="searchSrc" value="3"  style="display: inline" />&nbsp;الجزيرة</a></li>

<li ><a href="/ar/news/source/?source=4"><input type="radio" class="searchSrc" name="searchSrc" value="4"  style="display: inline" />&nbsp;شبكة رصد</a></li>
```

I want to preventDefault only for the parent hyperlink of the input while keeping the accessibility of changing the radios values i.e clicking them.

I tried the following:

```
$(".searchSrc").parent().click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).children('.searchSrc').attr('checked', this.checked);
      //also I tried to place event.preventDefault(); in this line
    })
```

However, I just able to click one time on a radio a button and I could not able to change the checked radio again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a>` tag has no `checked` property . Your `this` is the `<a>` element.

To fix what you were trying to do should use `prop()` and can use it with function callback as follows:

```
$(".searchSrc").parent().click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.searchSrc').prop('checked', function () {
        return !this.checked
    });

});
```

To work straight from the radios themselves would just do:

```
$(".searchSrc").click(function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I can't say that I understand why you would want radios inside an `<a>` tag...seems very strange to me.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cqLt59Lm/)**</kbd>

Comment: I will tell you: the list above is a navigation list. Also I have search features, on certain condition, I turned the search to be carried out among a specified source so in this condition, I want easily to turn this navigation list to act as a list for selecting source.

Comment: Please check the following update which shows a bug in the code, the value of radio does not changed it always the value of the first button. http://jsfiddle.net/cqLt59Lm/1/

Comment: not a bug at all.... your code isn't looking for checked radio like `$(".searchSrc:checked").val()` . If you use `val()` on more than one element will always return the first  http://jsfiddle.net/cqLt59Lm/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve in your setup, but if you don't want the anchor links around the inputs to be clickable, you should just remove them entirely and get rid of the javascript. They don't serve any purpose given what you're attempting to do. The radio buttons will be properly selectable at that point as well.

Answer (score 0):

The click listener should be on the `.searchSrc` elements and you should use `stopPropagation` instead of `preventDefault`

Comment: No I want the click on the link acting as the clicking on the radio.